# How to run onWindowFocusChanged as background service?

Tags: android, service, background-service

```
package com.vkstechnologies.servicedemo;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Vipul-Laptop on 03-01-2018.
 */

public class MyService extends Service {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(!hasFocus) {
            Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
        }
    }



}
```

I want to make an application that runs in background and detects whenever a power key is pressed to shut  down the phone and it just dismisses the "power off" window.
If I run this method in MainActivity, then it runs smoothly, but not in service.
The Error says : cannot resolve method onWindowFocusChanged

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573109/how-to-make-an-android-app-to-always-run-in-background

Comment: @GursheeshSingh Did you read my question??? I know how to create a service. I want to know how to run this 'onwindowsfocuschange' method in service??
The Error says : cannot resolve method onWindowFocusChanged

Comment: @GursheeshSingh  Now please upvote my question

Comment: You cannot because there is no method onWindowFocusChanged name in the superclass(Service)

Comment: @GursheeshSingh okay. But I know there's a way to do what I'm trying to do, because there are many apps on play store that do the same thing. For eg. Try Smart Lockscreen Protector. It does the same thing what I'm trying to achieve and without using any permission.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064523/detect-power-button-long-press

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157921/want-to-access-power-button-events-in-android

Comment: Hi Vipul, did you get answer, i also want the same to be implemented and searching. If u have achieved, pls guide.