# How do i detect device power button press when the app is locked and not in background

Tags: android

I am making an android app and I need to detect power button press twice even hen the app is not running in the background and send the SMS to the people while the device is locked. I don't want for the user to unlock the phone and then click on send to send the message.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157921/want-to-access-power-button-events-in-android

Comment: @IntsabHaider I dont think its duplicate.I saw the post you linked me to and that isnt working for me as it needs the application to be open in background. And i also want to know how to send the message in such a way that user doesnt need to press the send button.