# I am not getting the event when long press on power button on android 6.0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have implemented onKeyDown function in my activity and i want to open a dialog if we long press on power button. I have implemented that function as per following manner and working fine on older versions of android but isn't working on android 6.0

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER :
        if(event.isLongPress()){
            //Do something
            return true;
        }
        break;
    default : 
        break;
    }   
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) ;
}
```

Can you please help me.

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android

Comment: I have tried but there is no use.