# 4 times Power Button Pressed Call function

Tags: android

I have Created a methods to send `SMS` and call under function `callfunction();`
I want to call that function when the user have pressed four time power button, It should not required that app should be in launched state.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [Power Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

> PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK
>
> added in API level 1
>   int PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK
>   Wake lock level: Ensures that the CPU is running; the screen and keyboard backlight will be allowed to go off.
>
> If the user presses the power button, then the screen will be turned off but the CPU will be kept on until all partial wake locks have been released.
>
> Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)

Example:

```
//Initialize the Power Manager
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

 //Create a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK
 //This will keep the cpu running in the Background, so that the function will be called on the desired Time
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");

//Check if the WackLock is held (may throw erro if you try to acquire twice)
//TRUE --> Do nothing, all good
//FALSE --> Acquire the WakeLock
 if(!wl.isHeld()){
    wl.acquire();
 }

//*****
//You code to handel the Powerbutton comes here
//*****

//If the Repeating task is not active, release the Lock

//Check if the WackLock is held (may throw error if you try to release a none acquired Lock)
//TRUE --> Release Lock
//FALSE --> Do nothing, all good
 if(wl.isHeld()){
    wl.release();
 }
```

To handle the Power Button, check this Post:
[How to hook into the Power button in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android)

This is just an assumption, if it still doesnt work, could you post some Logs or more code snippets of your project :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible to keep track of power button press for 4 times and to start your expected functionality. Since i don't find any app on play store which has this kind of functionality so as to start there respected jobs. 
But you will get trigger for power button press for 1 time.