# How can I use the power button in the android?

Tags: java, android

I need an ideal way to use the power button in the android. I have a code but it does not work and when running onKeyLongPress it works with the power button and the device is closed or restarted..
So what is your suggestion for this problem ?!

In the first I used it in the manifest file ..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
```

Then I wrote the code at home..

```
@Override public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
    // Do something here...
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
```

}

So what is the problem ?

Comment: The power key is taken by the system to show the power dialog.  I don't think its passed to apps at all.

Comment: You can explain to me in more detail @GabeSechan

Comment: and If you have a way or another solution instead of better than this way .. You can tell me ! @GabeSechan

Comment: I'd really recommend against overriding the power button for any reason. Regardless, it looks like later API versions require [a more advanced method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39205226/608312).