# can we control the powerbutton of android mobiles?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, mobile

I want to send the emergency message by pressing the power button. How can we control the power button of android mobile phones by coding?. In ionic framework

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are searching for is available, check out the following link:
[How to hook into the Power button in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3703071/10399281)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called hardware_buttons which will help with your project.
here's the link:https://pub.dev/packages/hardware_buttons

Comment: Yaeh it is flutter plugin, can we do this by using ionic any idea...